Can we full uninstall Pulseaudio?
I use ubuntu studio 24.04.1 lts.
I've been having lot of problems with too much latency between my midi keyboard controller and the speakers final sound. There is an annoying delay between the moment I hit the key and the sound from the speakers. That delay makes almost impossible the full synchronizing between the keyboard and any prerecorded sound.
I've been testing with and without daws and/or other audio real time effects.
Also, I tested with different buffer sizes, polyphony and samples rates.
I tested it with parallel conections: one channel directly from qsynth to the computer output, and the other channel through pipewire, jack and calf processor, and... Is too noticeable the time difference between the direct connection vs the other!!!
The best I got was with 128 buffer size 44100 samples rate.
BUT... I cannot use that configuration because I get a lot of weird clicks and pops in the audio performance.
Also, I don't understand where in all this process is pulseaudio working, if it is working.
SO... As I know jack is necessary to some apps, I wonder if it is absolutely necessary to still use pulseaudio.
Maybe, the use of this is the reason of the latency. I don't know.
But, the question is still there:
Do we really need pulseaudio?
Can we full uninstall it?
Will we have problems without pulseaudio?

try doing this:

sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio pulseaudio-utils
sudo apt-get autoremove

then reboot and see if it works for you

I did it. Even the sound worked, almost, the latency problem remains the same. I reinstalled pulseaudio, jack, alsa and pipewire (through Synaptic) and all is working fine, but... The latency. I tested with buffer size of 256 and rate of 48000. It's working, yeah! But, I can feel the latency. I think the problem is something inside pipewire. But... I don't have any clue about that. Whatever, Thanks a lot for your time!!!
